# Trying to use two diffrent arrays to ask and answer questions

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-c++

I am trying to use 2 different arrays 1 for questions and the for answers but when I select the correct answer for any of the selected questions past "2" it always gives me incorrect answer and I cant see why can anyone held me please?

```
#include "Questions.h"

using namespace std;


//struct quiz
//{
//    string question[MAXITEMS];
//  string answers[MAXITEMS];
//};


const int MAXITEMS = 10;

int main ()
{
//quiz listQuiz[MAXITEMS];
//
//ifstream QuestionFile("Questions2.txt");
//char a;
//int count = 0;
//
//  if(!QuestionFile) // file testing
//  {
//    cout<< " error opening file" << endl;
//    return 1;
//  }
//
//  for (int i=0; i<MAXITEMS; i++)
//  {
//      QuestionFile>>listQuiz[i].

  //return 0;

    string question[MAXITEMS] = {"How_many_cards_of_each_suit_are_there?", "How_many_suits_are_there_in_a_standard_pack_of_cards?", "How_many_kings_are_in_a_standard_pack_of_cards?", "How_many_cards_are_in_a_standard_deck_of_cards?","How_many_black_suits_are_there_in_a_standard_pack_of_cards?", "How_many_red_suits_are_in_a_standard_pack_of_cards?", "Whats_the_number_of_the_card_that_comes_before_jack?", "How_many_cards_in_each_set_of_suits_are_there?", "What_is_the_lowest_number_in_a_standard_pack_of_cards?", "What_is_the_highest_number_in_a_standard_pack_of_cards?"};
    string answers[MAXITEMS] = {"4", "4", "4", "52", "2", "2", "10", "13", "2", "10"};

    int userInput = 0;
    int tries = 0;


    bool isGameOver = false;

    cout << "select 1 to start game" << endl;  //gives option to start and quit game
    cout << "select 2 to quit game" << endl;
    cin >> userInput;

    if (userInput == 2)
    {
        isGameOver = true;
        return 0;   
    };
    // error message if 1 or 2 is not input
    do
    {
        if (userInput!=1 && userInput!=2)
        {
            cout << " Your input is not valid! please try again:" << endl; // try switch cases for the different outcomes

            cout << "select 1 to start game" << endl;  
            cout << "select 2 to quit game" << endl;
            cin >> userInput;

            if (userInput == 2)
    {
        isGameOver = true;
        return 0;   
    };
            while (!(cin >> userInput))
            {
                cin.clear(); // clear the error flags
                cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n'); // discard the row

                cout << "Your input is not valid! please try again: ";

                cout << "select 1 to start game" << endl;  
                cout << "select 2 to quit game" << endl;
            }
            cout << userInput << endl;


        }
        // reprisent all characters as number to stop while roblem
        // when game starts gives option to select question and shows all questions
        if(userInput == 1)
        {

 //      // system("pause");
    //  //return-1;
 //// };

 // while(QuestionFile)      // while read is working
 // {
    //
    //      // for display

    //QuestionFile >> question[count];    // read into array
    //cout << count << " " << question << endl;
    // count++;

 // }
 // 
 // for (int i = 0; i < count ; ++i)
 // {cout << " array" << i << " is ::";
 // cout << question[i]<< endl;
 // }

 // cout << question[0]; //reads data in cell


 // //QuestionFile.close();

 // //system ("pause");
            do
            {
                cout << "select question" << endl;

                for(int i = 0; i != MAXITEMS; i++)
                {
                    cout << i << " " << question[i] << endl;
                }

                int selectQestion;
                cin >> selectQestion;

                if(selectQestion == 0||1||2||3||4||5||6||7||8||9  && tries != 2)
                {
                    cout << "Enter your answer" << endl;
                    string userAnswer;

                    cin >> userAnswer;

                    while (!(cin >> userAnswer))
                    {
                        cin.clear(); // clear the error flags
                        cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n'); // discard the row
                        cout << "Your input is not valid! please try again: ";
                    }

                    if (userAnswer == answers[0])
                    {
                        cout << "Correct answer" << endl;
                    }
                    else{

                        cout << "incorrect try again" << endl;
                        tries++;

                        cin >> userAnswer;
                        if (userAnswer == answers[0])
                        {
                            cout << "Correct answer" << endl;
                        }
                        else 
                            cout << "Incorrect" << endl;

                    }
                }
                if (selectQestion == 0||1||2||3||4||5||6||7||8||9  && tries == 2)
                {
                    cout << "you can no longer answer this question" << endl;
                    cout << "try another question" << endl;
                }

            }
            while(userInput == 1);

        }


    }
    while(isGameOver == false);

}
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm sure we've been through this before

```
if (selectQestion == 0||1||2||3||4||5||6||7||8||9  && tries == 2)
```

is incorrect. This version is correct.

```
if ((selectQestion == 0 || selectQestion == 1 || selectQestion == 2 || selectQestion == 3 || selectQestion == 4 || selectQestion == 5 || selectQestion == 6|| selectQestion == 7|| selectQestion == 8 || selectQestion == 9) && tries == 2)
```

But really you should use a little bit of logic and simplify, this version is even better

```
if (selectQestion >= 0 && selectQestion <= 9 && tries == 2)
```

Much better.

Fix that problem (you have it in at least two places) and if your program is still not working post again.

Comment: sorry bro when do it this way you have shown me it wont let me even enter a answer it just goes back to pick a question

Comment: Right, well as I said, if your code is still not working then post again. The problem is you have multiple errors in this code. The easy ones (like the one I fixed above) are going to get fixed first. Then we'll do the harder ones.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't make sense:

```
string question[MAXITEMS] = {"How_many_cards_of_each_suit_are_there?",
"How_many_suits_are_there_in_a_standard_pack_of_cards?",
"How_many_kings_are_in_a_standard_pack_of_cards?", 
"How_many_cards_are_in_a_standard_deck_of_cards?",
"How_many_black_suits_are_there_in_a_standard_pack_of_cards?", 
"How_many_red_suits_are_in_a_standard_pack_of_cards?", 
"Whats_the_number_of_the_card_that_comes_before_jack?", 
"How_many_cards_in_each_set_of_suits_are_there?", 
"What_is_the_lowest_number_in_a_standard_pack_of_cards?", 
"What_is_the_highest_number_in_a_standard_pack_of_cards?"};

string answers[MAXITEMS] = {"4", "4", "4", "52", "2", "2", "10", "13", "2", "10"};
```

To me, the answers and questions aren't in synch. And of course, it would be MUCH easier to deal with this if you have question and answer as part of a struct (or class):

```
struct QuestionAndAnswer
{
   std::string question;
   std::string answer;
}

QuestionAndAnswer qAndA[MAXITEMS] = 
{
   { "Question 1", "Answer for question 1" }, 
   { "Question 2", "Answer for question 2" },
   ...
};
```

And this code doesn't do what you think it does:

```
 if(selectQestion == 0||1||2||3||4||5||6||7||8||9  && tries != 2)
```

As suggested in another answer, you could do `if (selectOption == 0 || selectOption == 1 ...`, but I would suggest that you use a `switch` statement:

```
 switch(selectOption)
 {
    case 0:
    case 1:
     ... // more cases go here. 
    case 9:
       if (tries != 2)
        ... 
       else // tries == 2
        ... 
       break;
    default:
      ... Stuff to do when input was not a valid selection. 

      break;
  }
```

It is much easier to read a switch than a 11 item long if-condition.

A further problem is this:

```
do {
 ... 
} while(userInput == 1);
```

The variable `userInput` isn't changing inside that loop...

You also have a bug here:

```
 if (userAnswer == answers[0])
```

You probably want to check that the answer is the answer to the selected question, not the first question.

May I suggest that you develop smaller parts of the code at a time - change one little thing, test it, if it doesn't work, figure out why, then write a bit more code. I've not even compiled or run your code, and I've spotted at least four distinct errors that - yes, I've done programming for over 30 years, so I have some experience in spotting errors.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean because the first answers for the first 3 questions work its just the rest that dont

Comment: Your first question and answers don't match up - your first question is "How_many_cards_of_each_suit_are_there?", which should have the answer 13 as far as I know - unless a deck of cards has changed recently? And then, like everyone else has said, your if-statement for checking `SelectQestion` is wrong. And I just spotted another error... I will edit my answer to cover that one, as code looks awful in comments.

Answer (score -1):

This:

```
if (selectQestion == 0||1||2||3||4||5||6||7||8||9 ...)
```

is equivalent to:

```
if (selectQuestion == 1 ...)
```

The right hand side of the == sign is an expression for which C++ calculates a value and substitutes that value in place of that long series of ||'s.

Comment: No, it's `if ((selectQuestion == 0) || 1)`. `==` has higher precedence than `||`.